# A question on continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In Munkres' "Topology", Section 18, Example 3 (pg. 104), it is stated that the identity function

$$
g:\mathbb{R}_l\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, g(x)=x
$$

where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual topology and $\mathbb{R}_l$ has the lower limit topology, is continuous, because the inverse image of an open $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is the open set $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}_l$. But the basis of the $\mathbb{R}_l$ topology is formed by sets on the form $[c,d)$.

I figured out that $(a,b)$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}_l$ since
$$
(a,b)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left.[a-\frac{1}{n},b \right.)
$$
Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be fine if you wrote:

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b).$$

This way $a$ is not in that union.

Anyway, all you need to check is that the pre-image of any basis element is 
open. The above demonstrates that indeed, the pre-image is open because you expressed it as a union of open sets, which is again open.

Comment: Signal error! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Indeed if you read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) article this showed $R_{l}$ is finer than $R$ under usual topology.